# PDF viewer overlaps other objects on the page in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have an issue with a page browsing with Google chrome. When Google chrome plugin 'Chrome PDF Viewer' is disabled, the PDF being display overlaps every object. Below is a sample code.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: solid red 2px; position:absolute;z-index:100;background-color:Green;height:100px;width:250px;"></div>

    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:10;margin-left:100px;">
    <iframe visible="true" id="ipdf" src="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" height="1000" width="1000" runat="server" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" >

     </iframe>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it works any better e.g. in Internet Explorer with Adobe Reader plugin?
As far I know it has the same issue and you have to use another iframe for overlay areas.